# Magento 2 custom column sorting not working

Tags: magento2

I have created custom column in `Sales -> Order` **UI Grid**. I have added **"Profit"** column. Which is not related to any database table and not the attribute. This column display just calculation of profit.

The issue is I can not sort the column. Column is sortable but it is sorting incorrectly.

I have checked many similar question in stack but nothing helpfull. As the column is not in table and not the attribute.

Following is my override file.

**sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="total_paid" class="Company\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PurchasedPrice">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Profit</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">13</item>
                </item>
            </argument>

        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: No still not....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is already an old question, but it can be helpful for someone like me facing this issue.

According to this [Magento 2 GitHub issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4620), there is a `ui_bookmark` table where some settings about `UiComponents` (and **UI Grid** component in my case) are stored.

Truncating this table and clearing the cache in my case fixed the problem of columns `sortOrder` in **UI Grid**.